# How to build boost with mpi support on homebrew?

Tags: macos, boost, mpi, homebrew, openmpi

According to this post (https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/2953), the flag "`--with-mpi`" should enable boost_mpi build support for the related homebrew formula, so I am trying to install boost via homebrew like this:

```
brew install boost --with-mpi
```

However, the actual boost mpi library is not being build and can not be found.
There is currently some work being done around this, according to: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/pull/15689

In summary, I can currently build boost, but it seems the "`--with-mpi`" flag is being ignored. Could someone please check, if I should be able to build boost (with mpi support) on Mac OS X Mountain Lion (10.8)?

The (verbose) output generates these lines:

```
MPI auto-detection failed: unknown wrapper compiler mpic++
Please report this error to the Boost mailing list: http://www.boost.org
You will need to manually configure MPI support.

warning: skipping optional Message Passing Interface (MPI) library.
note: to enable MPI support, add "using mpi ;" to user-config.jam.
note: to suppress this message, pass "--without-mpi" to bjam.
note: otherwise, you can safely ignore this message.
```

Not sure how exactly I can fix this and get the mpi stuff to be build - any ideas?

Comment: There is some output of the build initialization here: https://gist.github.com/3981327

Comment: Older OS X versions used to ship with Open MPI preinstalled. I believe OMPI was dropped from Lion onwards and you would have to install it manually. The `bin` directory from the OMPI installation should be in the `PATH` - it is where `mpicc`, `mpic++`, etc. wrappers are located.

Comment: Thanks - yes I installed open-mpi, and just tried with mpich2 as well (still the same problem, though). The path is pointing to /usr/local/bin, which is where mpic++, mpicc, mpirun, etc. can be found, when you install with homebrew.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just in case this helps anyone else along the line, here's how I fixed this. The main error is `MPI auto-detection failed: unknown wrapper compiler mpic++`, any typing mpic++ at the command line verified that it was not working properly for me. I used brew to install open-mpi, but the same error was showing in the verbose output for installing boost. A run of `brew doctor` showed that openmpi was not linked properly, so I fixed those errors and reran `brew -v install boost --with-mpi --without-single` and it finally built and installed all of the libraries without a problem

Answer (score 3):

To anyone that comes across this, the package migrated to `boost-python` and `boost-mpi` separate from `boost`. Use `brew install boost-mpi`

Comment: This is helpful information, but I do believe that this should be a comment on the question, as it doesn't necessarily answer the question "how to build."

Answer (score 0):

Just get it worked on OSX 10.11.5. I've tried brew, but with no luck.

Suppose you already have gcc installed. Here are what I've done:

**1. Find and disable (but do not remove) clang**

clang alway cause headaches. There would be a lot of warnings when building Boost.

`which clang`, which should give you `/usr/bin/clang`

Rename it: `sudo mv clang clang_mac_remove`, also for clang++: `sudo mv clang++ clang++_mac_remove`. You can change the names back if you need them in future.

**2. Install OpenMPI**

If you already installed using brew, uninstall first. Becasue it would have used clang as the compiler wrapper by default. You need to change the wrapper to `gcc`.

Download the package.

Specify the wrapper compiler to `gcc` and `g++`:

```
./configure CC=gcc CXX=g++ F77=ifort FC=ifort --prefix=/usr/local
```

Below may take a long time.

```
make all

sudo make install
```

Reference: https://wiki.helsinki.fi/display/HUGG/Open+MPI+install+on+Mac+OS+X

**3. Install Boost MPI**

Download the package.

Run `./bootstrap.sh` (can open it first and specify the `toolset` to `gcc`, otherwise, the default option is `darwin` for mac).

Add `using mpi ;` in `project-config.jam` file. Then `./b2 —with-mpi` will only build the mpi library.

Then, all built libraries can be found in the folder `~/Downloads/boost_1_61_0/stage/lib`.

Copy or move them to `/usr/local/lib` or any other commonly used library path.

Reference: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/mpi/getting_started.html

**4. Compile with Boost MPI**

LIBRARY DIR = `-L/usr/local/lib`

INCLUDE = `-I/usr/local/include/`

LINKER = `-lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization`

e.g.

```
mpic++ -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include/ -c boost_test.cpp -L/usr/local/lib -lboost_mpi -lboost_serialization
```

Good luck!