# Make does not find dependencies of cpp file

Tags: c++, boost, cmake, makefile

I'm trying to install [voxcraft-sim](https://github.com/voxcraft/voxcraft-sim). I was able to follow their steps for a local install until the `cmake ..` step. After googling I found out that I needed to add the include directory and library directory by using the following code `cmake .. -DBOOST_INCLUDEDIR="/usr/include" -DBOOST_LIBRARYDIR="/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"`.

When now trying the next step `make -j 10`, I get the following error:
[image: error image]

As suggested by [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32898887/boost-no-longer-works-with-homebrew-on-mac-el-capitan), I changed the line to `make -j 10 -I "/usr/include"`. However, I still get the same issue. I'm running this on Ubuntu 20.04 using Cmake version 3.16 and Boost version 1.71.

As suggested by G.M. in the comments I ran `VERBOSE=1 make` to see the actual compiler invocation. This gave the following result `/opt/conda/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++   -I/project/home/app/voxcraft-sim/src -I/project/home/app/voxcraft-sim/src/VX3 -I/project/home/app/voxcraft-sim/src/Utils -I/project/home/app/voxcraft-sim/src/VXA -I/project/home/app/voxcraft-sim/src/old  -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -std=c++17 -fmessage-length=0 -march=nocona -mtune=haswell -ftree-vectorize -fPIC -fstack-protector-strong -fno-plt -O2 -ffunction-sections -pipe -isystem /opt/conda/include   -std=gnu++17 -o CMakeFiles/voxcraft-sim.dir/src/Executables/voxcraft-sim.cpp.o -c /project/home/app/voxcraft-sim/src/Executables/voxcraft-sim.cpp`. As you can see, the "usr/include" directory is not given as an extra include directory. Is there a way to make this work?

As suggested by @G.M. this is the list of default include search paths:
`/opt/conda/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/10.3.0/include /opt/conda/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/10.3.0/include-fixed /opt/conda/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include /opt/conda/bin/../lib/gcc/../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.3.0 /opt/conda/bin/../lib/gcc/../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.3.0/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu /opt/conda/bin/../lib/gcc/../../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/include/c++/10.3.0/backward /opt/conda/bin/../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include`

Comment: Are you sure boost is present under /usr/include ?

Comment: Yes! I double checked it and the directory 'boost' is present under 'usr/include'.

Comment: And it has `program_options.hpp` file there?

Comment: Run `VERBOSE=1 make` to see the compiler invocation that's actually being used.

Comment: @ixSci Yes it is present in the directory.

Comment: @G.M. I added the result to my question :) as you can see 'make' does not include the provided include directory.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the output of `/opt/conda/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-c++ -xc++ /dev/null -E -Wp,-v 2>&1 | sed -n 's,^ ,,p'` .  That should show a list of the default include search paths.

Comment: @G.M. I added the output!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by creating a symbolic link from the boost directory in '/usr/include' to '/opt/conda/bin/../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include' with the following command `ln -s /usr/include/boost /opt/conda/bin/../x86_64-conda-linux-gnu/sysroot/usr/include/boost`