# Boost.MPI gives Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

I am trying to run the basic ["Hello, World!" example](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/mpi/tutorial.html):

```
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>
#include <iostream>
namespace mpi = boost::mpi;

int main()
{
  mpi::environment env;
  mpi::communicator world;
  std::cout << "I am process " << world.rank() << " of " << world.size()
            << "." << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have tried numerous variants for running this program:

```
mpic++ -I /usr/local/include/ test.cpp -o test -lboost_system
```

also:

```
mpic++ -I /usr/local/include/boost test.cpp -o test -lboost_system
```

and using `mpicc`, and `clang++` as a substitute. Each combination gives the follow error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "boost::mpi::environment::environment(bool)", referenced from:
      _main in test-b0215f.o
  "boost::mpi::environment::~environment()", referenced from:
      _main in test-b0215f.o
  "boost::mpi::communicator::communicator()", referenced from:
      _main in test-b0215f.o
  "boost::mpi::communicator::rank() const", referenced from:
      _main in test-b0215f.o
  "boost::mpi::communicator::size() const", referenced from:
      _main in test-b0215f.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Homebrew says that both MPICH2 and boost1.63.0 are installed. I can confirm that `mpic++` runs by compiling and then running [this program:](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/mpi/)

```
   // required MPI include file  
   #include "mpi.h"
   #include <stdio.h>

   int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
   int  numtasks, rank, len, rc; 
   char hostname[MPI_MAX_PROCESSOR_NAME];

   // initialize MPI  
   MPI_Init(&argc,&argv);

   // get number of tasks 
   MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&numtasks);

   // get my rank  
   MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD,&rank);

   // this one is obvious  
   MPI_Get_processor_name(hostname, &len);
   printf ("Number of tasks= %d My rank= %d Running on %s\n", numtasks,rank,hostname);


        // do some work with message passing 


   // done with MPI  
   MPI_Finalize();
   }
```

Which produces the correct output.

I have also verified that (at least part of) Boost is installed by compiling and successfully running the [Boost "Hello, World!"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_63_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial.html)

```
//
// timer.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2016 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time/posix_time/posix_time.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::asio::io_service io;

  boost::asio::deadline_timer t(io, boost::posix_time::seconds(5));
  t.wait();

  std::cout << "Hello, world!" << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

with:

```
clang++ -I /usr/local/include/ timer.cpp -o timer -lboost_system
```

How can I get the Boost.MPI example to run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get linker errors from boost, you usually forgot to link against a boost library.

There is also a boost_mpi library, so you should compile with

```
clang++ -I /usr/local/include/ timer.cpp -o timer -lboost_system -lboost_mpi
```

Note that you need a boost version with support for mpi.

- Generally consider http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/mpi/getting_started.html
- Specifically with homebrew you can check [How to build boost with mpi support on homebrew?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143409/how-to-build-boost-with-mpi-support-on-homebrew)

Comment: My computer can't seem to find it `ld: library not found for -lboost_mpi`. Maybe Homebrew doesn't install it by default or something?

Comment: So, there is a brew formula for boost-mpi. I am going to try this out and see if it works.

Comment: Yes, seems to be so, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13143409/how-to-build-boost-with-mpi-support-on-homebrew

Comment: OK, added the links to my answer. Hope this is enough to answer your question.